# Scheduled job from Flask application

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, scheduled-tasks

I am hoping to gain a basic understanding of scheduled task processes and why things like Celery are recommended for Flask.

My situation is a web-based tool which generates spreadsheets based on user input. I save those spreadsheets to a temp directory, and when the user clicks the "download" button, I use Flask's "send_from_directory" function to serve the file as an attachment. I need a background service to run every 15 minutes or so to clear the temp directory of all files older than 15 minutes.

My initial plan was a basic python script running in a while(True) loop, but I did some research to find what people normally do, and everything recommends Celery or other task managers. I looked into Celery and found that I also need to learn about redis, and I need to apparently host redis in a unix environment. This is a lot of trouble for a script that just deletes files every 15 minutes.

I'm developing my Flask app locally in Windows with the built-in development server and deploying to a virtual machine on company intranet with IIS. I'm learning as I go, so please explain why this much machinery is needed to regularly call a script that simply deletes things. It seems like a vast overcomplication, but as I said, I'm trying to learn as I go so I want to do/learn it correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use Celery or redis for this. A cron job would be perfectly appropriate.

Celery is for jobs that need to be run asynchronously but in response to events in the main server processes. For example, if a sign up form requires sending an email notification, that would be scheduled and run via Celery so as not to block the main web response.

Comment: Since I'm deploying to a Windows environment, would the alternative to a Cron job be a windows scheduler, or will my simple "while(True)" script running in the background be sufficient?

I guess I don't understand why separate machinery is required, such as Cron or a Windows scheduler.

Comment: But what would run the while loop? What would start it up when your server starts, or restart it if it dies? Scheduled tasks aren't separate machinery anyway, they're built into your operating system.